# How to delete removed items of datagridview from database after button click event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and Save `Button` in my form. I am adding a purchased items from `TextBoxes` to `DataGridView` and after clicking Save `Button` it saves to database. Here is the code for same -

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrderList.Rows)
        {
            if ((bool)row.Cells[0].Value)
            {
                int productId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["clmCode"].Value);
                int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["clmQty"].Value);
                int amount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["clmAmount"].Value);

                if (_orderBLL.CreateOrderedProduct(productId, quantity, amount, orderId))
                {
                    status = true;
                    row.Cells[0].Value = false;
                }
                else
                    status = false;
            }
        }
```

I have one more `Button` called Remove for deleting the items from purchased item list. Here is the code for same -

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrderList.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Selected)
                {
                    dgvOrderList.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
                    int div = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value);

                    total = total - div;
                    txtTotalAmount.Text = total.ToString();
                    if (!(bool)row.Cells[0].Value)
                    {
                        int productId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
                        int orderId = Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderId.Text);
                        if(_orderBLL.IsOrderedProductExists(productId, orderId))
                        {
                            _orderBLL.DeleteOrderedProducts(productId, orderId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But the problem is, when I click Remove `Button` it instantly removes item from `DataGridView` as well as from Database instead of waiting to Save.

My question, is there any way that I can only removes item from `DataGridView` by clicking Remove `Button` and then removes from database after clicking Save `Button`?

Comment: why don't you get the selected row.. find the KeyId and make a Method that does a Delete from the Database where ProductID = to the selected rows productId or the OrderId, use the debugger to step through the code to see if you are passing the expected value you your `DeleteOrderedProducts` Method

Comment: Instead of calling `_orderBLL.DeleteOrderedProducts(productId, orderId);` from your delete button, you should be doing that in the save method for any deleted items. This means that when you delete an item from the grid, you'll need remember the deleted items (say in a list) and access them at save time.

Comment: @MethodMan my question is after removing the items from `DataGridView` control how could I delete those from database at the time of saving.. if I can't use get selected row method for removed items from `DataGridView`

Comment: @OhBeWise.. thanks for the suggestion.. I will try it and will let you know the result

Comment: @OhBeWise... I tried exactly same as you suggested and it works perfectly fine... Thanks!

Comment: Well done working it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution for above problem as per suggestions in above comments.

Changes in Remove `Button`. Added integer array `pids[]` to store the products ids which will remove from `DataGridView` and then same will be check while saving the order and delete from database.

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrderList.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Selected)
                {
                    dgvOrderList.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
                    //break; //use break if you only select one row! if selected more, then remove it!
                    pids[i] = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
                    i++;

                    int div = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value);

                    total = Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalAmount.Text);
                    total = total - div;
                    txtTotalAmount.Text = total.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Updated below code in Save `Button`

```
                foreach (int p in pids)
                {
                    if (p != 0)
                        _orderBLL.DeleteOrderedProducts(p, orderId);
                }
```